# Database schema - Creating a private messaging based on an 'item'

Tags: php, mysql

`users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_id` varchar(23) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_id` (`unique_id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`items` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_photo` text,
  `item_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_price` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `fk_category_id` (`category_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `items_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What I would wanna do is to create a private messaging system for my project. Before this I have implemented a Comment system and it works well (pull out `comments` which has the same `item_id`). You can see the DDL and query [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9UcRBXjC). But when it come to this, I find it hard to think about private messaging model.

Basically, the private message is **to bid the item price** between **TWO users** only (the seller and the bidder). Other registered user cannot see others bidding.

Here's my try at creating `Bids` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `bids` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bid` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_uid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_uid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_iid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have also tried to make Foreign Keys into `bids` table, but it seems like it's already too complicated for me. So an error *1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint* came out :(

If anything just let me know.

---

**EDIT:** charset to utf8. Failed to create Foreign key constraints

Comment: You should synch your table encodings.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;` vs. `ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;` -- This might not be the cause of your question, but having all in utf8 prevents from a lot of other issues.

Comment: Changed all to utf8. Still, failed to make constraints.

Comment: Are you having a bid with every message? It might be worthwhile to make a messages, bids and conversation table.

Comment: `message` in bids table is just a message together with the bidding price. So it's more like a conversation between two people about an item. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

**MESSAGES**

```
message_id
conversation_id
user_id
message
```

**CONVERSATIONS**

```
conversation_id
item_id
user_id
```

**BIDS**

```
bid_id
item_id
user_id
amount
```